# Threading/multiprocessing in replacement to dictionary in discord.py music bot

Tags: python, multithreading, discord, multiprocessing, bots

I watched a video where a man used dictionary to run a music bot on few different discord servers and the code looks like this:

```
  #.... __init__..... self.vc = {}
  async def join_VC(self, ctx, channel):
        id = int(ctx.guild.id)
        if self.vc[id] == None or not self.vc[id].is_connected():
            self.vc[id] = await channel.connect()

            if self.vc[id] == None:
                await ctx.send("Could not connect to the vouce channel.")
                return
        else:
            await self.vc[id].move_to(channel)
```

My question is: Is it possible to use threading or multiprocessing in replacement to dictionary? If yes then what do you guys reccomend?

full code: https://github.com/TheRealDulanOoga/GeraldTheRobot/tree/6aeec689b9a533527abfea54298ae88a0bd4d691

I don't know if I should use multiprocessing on whole class (is it possible?) or just on few functions. I'm a bit confused I need an advice.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. `threading` and `multiprocessing` are libraries for parallel code execution, while dictionaries are a basic lookup table data structure. They're completely different things that do completely different things.

Comment: what I meant is you need to do some process concurrency right? If not then bot will play the same music on all discord servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your function is already async, means it can run parallel. So there is really no nead for threading it ...

threading simply means you create a process that runs the function

async means this function wont block the code

and the result you want is only to not block the code, of course can you thread the function but there would be no benefits by doing so